# Combine two sentences with some words missing in both or any one

Tags: python, c++, string, algorithm, data-structures

```
Input 1 - 'My name is Mayank'
Input 2 - 'My will name not Mayank'

Output - 'My will name is not Mayank' or 'My will name not is Mayank'
```

I want to combine two string, both of them may contain some extra words (which is missing in the other). If there are multiple outputs, then please give any.

Please provide any hints or code in Python or C++.

Update - Order of words should be maintained, and it is given that all the common words will be in same order in both the inputs.

Comment: Do you want an answer in a particular order of words?

Comment: The output is not making sense to me. Can you explain?

Comment: @vivek_23 I mean the order of words... That is can I answer like this 'is Mayank My name not will'.

Comment: @YashShah I asked Mayank.

Comment: This sounds very similar to what is done by the "diff" algorithms, like GNU diff or git diff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Comment: @YashShah yes the order should be maintained and it is given that all the common words will be same order in both the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep note of the set of words preceding every word in each sentence you get

```
{'My':     set(),
 'name':   {'My', 'will'},
 'is':     {'My', 'name'},
 'Mayank': {'My', 'is', 'name', 'not', 'will'},
 'will':   {'My'},
 'not':    {'My', 'name', 'will'}}
```

You can then iterate on the list generating words whose complete set of preceding words have already been generated.

Here's the Python:

```
from collections import defaultdict


s1 = 'My name is Mayank'
s2 = 'My will name not Mayank'
s = [s1.strip().split(), s2.strip().split()]

keyaftervalues = defaultdict(set)
for phrase in s:
    for i, this in enumerate(phrase):
        keyaftervalues[this] |= set(phrase[:i])
keyaftervalues = dict(keyaftervalues)

sofar, sofarlist = set(), []
while keyaftervalues:
    consider = []
    for this, preceders in keyaftervalues.items():
        if sofar.issuperset(preceders):
            others = preceders - sofar
            consider.append((this, len(others), len(preceders)))
    if consider:
        consider.sort(key=lambda x:x[1:])
        last = consider[0][0]
        sofar.add(last)
        sofarlist.append(last)
        del keyaftervalues[last]
answer = ' '.join(sofarlist)

print(answer)   # My will name is not Mayank
```

Comment: This code has a infinite loop when strings has duplicate word. Example: `s1 = 'you stop then stop'` and `s2 = 'then they stop'`

Comment: @natielle: getting good test input is an issue. If you ever ask for help then spare some thought for a good test/example case.